# How to pass in variables with a redirect?

Tags: python, django, redirect

So I have a signup on my base.html, then the form redirects to a signup page.

```
def signIn(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        context = {
            "extendVar":"baseLoggedIn.html",
        }
        return HttpResponseRedirect("out")
    if request.user.is_authenticated()==False:
        # form=SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
        if request.method=="POST":

            email=request.POST.get('email','')
            password = request.POST.get('password','')

            user = auth.authenticate(username=email,password=password)

            print(email)
            print(password)
            print(user)
            if user is not None:
                print("notNone")
                auth.login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect("out")
            else:
                print("None quàlol")
                context={
                    "failure":"Password and e-mail did not match",
                }
                return HttpResponseRedirect("out") #redirects to base.html
        context = {
            "extendVar":"baseNotLoggedIn.html",
        }
    return render(request, "base.html",context)
```

the only problem is, when I do this, it redirects to the home page, but the home page doesn't have any errors, and I can't figure out a way to display the error that the password + email did not match, since i'm redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your message as part of context, and your `HttpResponseRedirect` does not take any context as a parameter, so you need to `return render(request, "base.html", context)` instead of `HttpResponseRedirect`. Then you can access the `"failure"` key from `context`.

Also, keep your code clean!

```
def sign_in(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        context = {
            "extendVar":"baseLoggedIn.html",
        }
        return HttpResponseRedirect("out")
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']

                user = auth.authenticate(username=email, password=password)

                print(email)
                print(password)
                print(user)
                if user:
                    print("notNone")
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect("out")
                else:
                    print("None quàlol")
                    context={
                        "failure":"Password and e-mail did not match",
                    }
                    return render(request, "base.html", context)
            else:  # form invalid, pass as variable back to user with form errors
                return render(request, "base.html", {'form': form}
        context = {
            "extendVar":"baseNotLoggedIn.html",
        }
    return render(request, "base.html",context)
```

Comment: ok, the only problem is I have a form on my base.html which is not being extended because I was only extending it in the original form...it's a bit of a hassle to put it in 2 places at once. is there any more elegant way of doing this? also, i would do the forms like you are doing, but this form is only for signing in and doesnt have a forms.py or anything like that. can I still do if form.is_valid() etc?